# Elegant wat to join dataframe by name then autofill blank value by pandas, create a coloured scatter plot according value using matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, merge, scatter-plot

I am wondering is there an elegant and efficient way to achieve what my title as stated.

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = pd.DataFrame([['ad_001','50'], ['ad_002', '100'], ['ad_003', '150']],columns=['name', 'score'])
  
data2 = pd.DataFrame([['ad_001','75'], ['ad_002', '200'], ['ad_004', '100']],columns=['name', 'score'])
```

I tried using

```
data1.merge(data2, how='left', left_on='name', right_on='name')
```

to merge the two dataframes.

My aim is to join the following dataframes and auto-fill the missing values :

```
data1 = pd.DataFrame([['ad_001','50','75'], ['ad_002', '100', '200'], ['ad_003', '150', '0'], ['ad_004', '0', '100']],columns=['name', 'score_x','score_y'])
```

Then I want to show a scatterplot of the data using matplotlib and colour each point according to the maximum score of x and y.

- if x or y >100, colour red
- if x or y >150, colour green
- if x or y >200, colour red.

I tried looking at
[https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_with_legend.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-scatter-with-legend-py] the userguide but do quite know how to implement it.

Or is there any other plotting python modules that one would recommend to achieve the same outcome ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part of merging the two dataframes, one of the ways to do this is to use merge and use `outer` so that all columns are captured. This will include all rows with `nan` where no data is available. Using `.fillna(0)` will handle this - based on how you mentioned you want the invalid number to appear.

For the conditions and plotting, the simplest way would be to use something like `np.where()`, which you can use to identify the colors you want. As your question had `red` for two conditions, I have made one as red, while the other is blue. You can adjust the numbers and colors are you need. Once the column with colors is available, using `groupby()` and plotting will give you the results you need. Hope this helps...

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data1 = pd.DataFrame([['ad_001','50'], ['ad_002', '100'], ['ad_003', '150']],columns=['name', 'score'])
data2 = pd.DataFrame([['ad_001','75'], ['ad_002', '200'], ['ad_004', '100']],columns=['name', 'score'])

newdata=pd.merge(data1, data2, on="name", how='outer').fillna(0) ## Merge & fillna()
newdata['score_x']=newdata['score_x'].astype('int64') ## Convert to int as you are comparing
newdata['score_y']=newdata['score_y'].astype('int64') ## Convert to int as you are comparing

##Use np.where to create color column with the colors you need
newdata['color']=np.where(((newdata.score_x<100) & (newdata.score_y<100)), 'red', 
                       np.where(((newdata.score_x<150) & (newdata.score_y<150)), 'green', 'blue'))

## Group and plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for clr, d in newdata.groupby('color'):
    ax.scatter(x=d['score_x'],y=d['score_x'], label=clr)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for your kind assistance. I would definitely test it out tonight.

Comment: Thank you very much. I managed to plot the scatter plot i wanted for so long. Additional question, when i appended my data, i noted some of the dataset has a duplicated name, e.g. ad_001, 100,200, ad_001 50,0.  I tried using newdata.drop_duplicates(subset='name', keep="first"), but it doesnt work. Is there a way to only keep the first appearance of name?

Comment: Thank you again. I figured it out at the end with using 
newdata = newdata[~newdata.name.duplicated(keep='first')]